# how can use the network to store and retrieve data?

Tags: android

I need to store data on a website using android and retrive data from this site to use this data in my project.
How is possible Or is it possible????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First you need a server in which you can create physical  database  and store and make web-services.if you dont aware with parser then give you some link**

[**First**](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152)
[**Second**](http://www.roseindia.net/xml/sax/SAXParserCheck.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

You can either create your own website and implement a service for storing your data, or you can use an existing web service. For example, Amazon Web Services (AWS) gives you several options, e.g.:

- Amazon S3 is good for storing arbitrary data objects
- Amazon SimpleDb is a simple non-relational database

Amazon has the [Android SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/) for interfacing with all those services.

You can learn more about AWS at the [AWS website](http://aws.amazon.com).

There are web services by other companies as well, e.g. : [Microsoft Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/)

These services cost money if you use them intensively, but for a small amount of data you usually don't have to pay anything.

Comment: I have a website..How can i store retrieve data in this site." I am new user in android"

Comment: A simple answer: create a request handler that would look at the parameters of the request and send the appropriate data in the response. In your Android app, implement a custom HTTP client that would form correct requests and parses the response. If you need help on a specific technology, please ask (in a new question). It's hard to be more specific without knowing what kind of webserver do you use.

Answer (score 0):

With [C2DM you can notify devices](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) that new data is available.

For storing the data you can use :

- [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) - Amazon web services
- or if you have your own SQL server setup a http webservice or WCF webservice.

Answer (score 0):

If you that website provides its android api then it well and good to use that api for the work that you wnat to do.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use web services call. There are 2 Parts

Server Part

1->create a web service for store data
2->Create a web service for fetch data in xml or json format

Android part

1->send data  with the help of web service
2->retrieve data  with the help of web service

There is some usefull liks
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-dataAndroid/index.html